# Angular 7 httpClient get response from Laravel API is string

Tags: javascript, php, angular

I have an Angular 7 project with a PHP Laravel API backend that is returning json from get requests.

return Response::json($genres);

I'm using httpClient in a service which is being called from a component (see both below). When I console log the data it is a string, not a json object. Also I am unable to access any of the properties that it has because it is just a long string.

In most online examples people used map and then pipe but those are both deprecated now and apparently httpClient just returns JSON as default but that is not what appears to be happening in this case.

Could someone give me a solution to this? I need access to the data in the response as JSON.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getGenres(){
      return this.http.get('http://www.localhost:7888/api/genres', this.genre);
  }


}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-genres',
  templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./genres.component.css']
})
export class GenresComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      // make http request to http://www.localhost:7888/api/genres
      this.apiService.getGenres().subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
      },
      error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: are you sure that the API  is sending data as json , did you check it with postman

Comment: also try setting the header `const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};` and pass it with the Api call in the service